# Enable/Find VAT Registration Number Billing Address?

Tags: magento2, vat

I can see references all over Magento settings for the VAT reg number but I cannot find it using the store as a customer. Is there a setting to enable it on registration and to edit it later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be enabled via admin panel:

Stores > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Show Tax/VAT Number

The possible options are:

- No
- Optional
- Required